# Azure Web App Authentication / Authorization issue

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am trying to authenticate my Azure Web App. Follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication)

In my Azure Portal, I've selected "Authenticate / Authorization" for my Web App.
After I configure my Microsoft Account Authentication Settings with Client ID/Key from the App Registration page, I save the settings page and I'll see an error:
[image]
The errors says:

> Failed to save Auth Settings for ***WebApp*** App:
> {"Code":"Conflict","Message":"Cannot update the site '***WebApp***' because
> Authentication / Authorization was configured with an invalid issuer
> URL ''. The URL must be well-formed, absolute, and use the HTTPS
> scheme.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Cannot update the site
> '***WebApp***' because Authentication / Authorization was configured with an
> invalid issuer URL ''. The URL must be well-formed, absolute, and use
> the HTTPS
> scheme."},{"Code":"Conflict"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"04530","MessageTemplate":"Cannot
> update the site '{0}' because Authentication / Authorization was
> configured with an invalid issuer URL '{1}'. The URL must be
> well-formed, absolute, and use the HTTPS
> scheme.","Parameters":["***WebApp***",""],"Code":"Conflict","Message":"Cannot
> update the site '***WebApp***' because Authentication / Authorization was
> configured with an invalid issuer URL ''. The URL must be well-formed,
> absolute, and use the HTTPS scheme."}}],"Innererror":null}

I'm not sure what's the "invalid issuer URL" the issue is referring to.

Comment: Go to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com  and Check if the Redirect URLs in your Application is like this: `https://<the URL of your App>/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback` and the application platform is `Web`.

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: Even still got the error ?

Comment: I changed my region to another one and it worked! Thanks @WayneYang-MSFT

Comment: I am having the exact same issue in Central US, for google authentication! 

>"Cannot update the site '**mysite**' because Authentication / Authorization was configured with an invalid issuer URL '**myurl**'. The URL must be well-formed, absolute, and use the HTTPS scheme.

I followed the directions in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication

My application works - I can access API endpoints on it. But for some reason, this is not working.

Comment: So I republished my app to US West 2, and it *works* there. This is very bizarre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is not a general issue. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication) is absolutely correct.

So I suggest you try to use another location to deploy your Web App and configure the Applicaiton again.

Also, this issue should be temporary, I have reported this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I'm on the App Service team. This is a known issue which we are working to address - the behavior should be temporary. Our apologies for any issues this has caused.

I do not recommend the solution of moving to another region, as this is not guaranteed to work, and sites that do see resolution in this way may break again.

Please find our recommended workaround instructions in my response to [this forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb89c3cb-2e01-4572-b143-f5737f39d749/error-saving-authentication-authorization-settings?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Comment: Followed the advice given in this forum post by manually setting the values for google auth and it is working fine. While manually editing authconfig, I left issuer property to null as it was and still no issues.

Comment: I made changes to the instructions but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to add AAD as an auth provider with the default setting even though I'm not using it. I was then able to save my Facebook auth settings. This is a temporary workaround.
This answer from this [discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fb89c3cb-2e01-4572-b143-f5737f39d749/error-saving-authentication-authorization-settings?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). Edit field "issuer" not working for me.